# フォルダ名に空白があっても動作するシェルスクリプトを書きたい

Tags: bash, shellscript

shell scriptで任意のフォルダの中の.bashファイルの有無を確認して
任意の存在すればshellscriptのあるフォルダに保存するプログラムを書いています。

その際にフォルダ名に空白があると失敗してしまいます。
shellscriptののある絶対パスに空白がないフォルダであれば成功しました。

空白に\が付いてしまうのが原因で,pwdで出力した空白に\をつける方法はありますでしょうか？
また下記のコードで注意する点や改善点などありますでしょうか？

```
#!/bin/bash
current=$(cd $(dirname $0) && pwd)
filearray=(".bashrc" ".bash_profile" ".bash_history" "index.html")

for item in ${filearray[@]}; do
  if [ -e $HOME/$item ]; then
    echo "$item found"
    filepath=$HOME/$item
    copy=cp $filepath $current
  else
    echo "$item Not found"
  fi
done
```

Comment: 質問というか、疑問というか、そのままだとエラーになると思うのですが、`copy=cp $filepath $current`はどういう意図でしょうか？　回答にある通り単に`cp`したいだけでしょうか?

Comment: まだ初心者なので現段階だと、コピーだけできればと思っています。
皆様のアドバイスのおかげで自分で意図した通りには動作しました。

これから自動でファイルを保存したり、更新したりと
色々拡張できればと考えております。

何か拡張した方が良い機能や参考になることなどありますでしょうか？

Comment: であれば質問の本質とは関わらない部分なのでfilearrayの定義部と同様に修正してしまっても構わないと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

初めに、配列の定義部分で".bashrc"と".bash_profile"の間だけ`,`が含まれており、このままだとひと続きの要素として認識されていると思うので正しくは

```
filearray=(".bashrc" ".bash_profile" ".bash_history" "index.html")
```

---

質問に対する回答ですが、if文の中でコピーを行う箇所で、`$current`をダブルクォーテーションで括るのはどうでしょう。

```
  if [ -e $HOME/$item ]; then
    echo "$item found"
    filepath=$HOME/$item
    cp $filepath "$current"
  else
```

Comment: `$HOME` に空白が含まれるかもしれないので、変数を利用している他の部分もすべてクォートするのはいかがですか？

Comment: 「値に空白が含まれる可能性のある変数」をクォートでくくっておくのは安全のためそうすべきだと思いますが、そもそもファイル名やフォルダ名には今回のようなトラブルを避けるためにも空白を含めるべきではないと思います。質問でOSは明記されていませんが、Linuxなどの場合`$HOME`は`/home`+`ユーザ名`となり、、ユーザ名に空白は含められないはずです。

Comment: ホームディレクトリは[変更できる](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20797819/5989200)ので、`$HOME` にも空白が入り得ます。パスに空白を入れない方がオススメ、というのはユーザー側の自衛策としてはごもっともなのですが、開発者側としてはなるべく一般的な環境において動作するように作る方が良いのではないかと思います。

Answer (score 2):

古い話題だが、雑なスクリプトすぎてモヤモヤするので、ちゃんと書いておく。

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -u

dst=$(cd $(dirname "$0") && pwd) || exit $?
items=(".bashrc" ".bash_profile" ".bash_history" "index.html")

for item in "${items[@]}"; do
  src="$HOME/$item"
  if [ -e "$src" ]; then
    echo "$item found"
    cp -- "$src" "$dst/"
  else
    echo "$item Not found"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

既に回答されている通りでこの場合は変数をクォートしてあげれば解決しますが、何らかの理由で空白をエスケープしたいこともあるかもしません。
そういう場合は`"${current// /\\ }"`としてあげるとbashのパラメータの展開を利用して実現できます。